# Cannot print array elements in loop, error cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]'

Tags: c#, arrays, string, printing, element

I am trying to print each line of string in my array into a separate text file, but I cannot seem to have the array with index in my data source, I keep getting in my data source at the `WriteAllLines()` method, the error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]'

for having `T_tag[l]`.

Can somebody help me understand this error?

```
string[] Colmn_No = ColmnN.ToArray();

int ArrayLength = Colmn_No.Length;    

string[] Cleantag = new string[ArrayLength];
string[] CleanCage = new string[ArrayLength];
for (int i = 0; i <= ArrayLength - 1; i++)
{
    Cleantag[i] = Colmn_SmpNm[i].Trim().ToUpper();   
    CleanCage[i] = Colmn_Cage[i].Trim().ToUpper();  
}


string[] T_tag = new string[ArrayLength];
string[] A_tag = new string[ArrayLength];
for (int k = 0, l=0, m=0; k <= ArrayLength - 1; k++)
{
    if (Cleantag[k].StartsWith("T"))    
    {  
        T_tag[l] = "<T>"+ Cleantag[k]+"</T><C>C</C><V>"+ CleanCage[k]+"</V>";

        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines((RRfolder + "//" + Cleantag[k] + ".txt"), T_tag[l]);
        l++;
    }
```

Comment: Is T_tag meant to me an array of length 0? maybe you want length of 1?

Comment: Your `T_tag` can hold 0 elements. Your `Cleantag` is undefined. Put a little more effort in asking a question.

Comment: i guess i did not document well,

Comment: i have updated the code i used to show correctly.

Comment: T-tag is mean to be an array of length ArrayLength

Comment: Cleantag  definition was missing, a little patience can help

Comment: please review the problem again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//System.IO.File.WriteAllLines((RRfolder + "//" + Cleantag[k] + ".txt"), T_tag[l]);
```

1) Write 1 line

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText((RRfolder + "//" + Cleantag[k] + ".txt"), T_tag[l]);
```

2) Or, write all lines (do that outside the for-loop)

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines((RRfolder + "//" + Cleantag[k] + ".txt"), T_tag);
```